# String with semicolon delimeter regexp

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
; 2017-01-01; 2017-01-01; ; 2017-01-01
```

At start of string, there is only semicolon (`;`), not space and semicolon ( `;`). And my regexp, `[^;]+`, does not work properly. How can I get 5 values from this string?

```
1 empty
2 data
3 data
4 empty
5 data
```

Comment: Please help us to help you by making your question readable and formatting your code.

Comment: Please show the relevant part of the code.

Comment: What if the 1st and  4th items are NULL? `TRIM` returns `NULL` when the input is blank. Will it be OK?

Answer (score 1):

you should use the regex

```
[^;]*
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/CRzaWM/1)

Comment: this regex, make from this string:
1 empty, 2 data, 3 empty, 4 data, 5,6,7 empty, 8 data, 9 empty

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: i have in my select - trim(regexp_substr(t.data_inst_gen, '[^;]+', 1, levels.column_value))

Comment: use [^;]* instead of [^;]+

Comment: @crisx Is that Oracle?

Comment: yes i very long query, and i need regex in part of this

Comment: [^;]* - this regex not work what i need, i tried on regex101

Answer (score 0):

You may add a space before each `;` and then use `[^;]+` and `TRIM` each item you get:

```
SELECT rtrim(ltrim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(str, ';', ' ;'), '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL))) AS substr
FROM (
    SELECT '; 2017-01-01; 2017-01-01; ; 2017-01-01' AS str FROM DUAL
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '[^;]+')) + 1
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/KQJX95465), output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

This regular expression

```
(?:^|[^;])(?:(?!;).)*(?=;|$)
```

[image]

Will do the following:

- match all strings delimited by `;` character
- match the first empty string if the source text starts with a `;`
- match the last empty string  if the source text ends with a `;`
- not return the `;` as part of the match

## Examples

See also [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QKrFjg/3)

Given the source text

**Note** : the first line ends with a `;` followed by no spaces, and the second line ends with a `;` followed by one space

```
; 2017-01-02; 2017-01-03; ; 2017-01-05;
; 2017-01-08; 2017-01-09; ; 2017-01-11;
```

Returns the following

```
Match 1
Full match  0-0 ``
Match 2
Full match  1-12    ` 2017-01-02`
Match 3
Full match  13-24   ` 2017-01-03`
Match 4
Full match  25-26   ` `
Match 5
Full match  27-38   ` 2017-01-05`
Match 6
Full match  39-40   `
`
Match 7
Full match  40-40   ``
Match 8
Full match  41-52   ` 2017-01-08`
Match 9
Full match  53-64   ` 2017-01-09`
Match 10
Full match  65-66   ` `
Match 11
Full match  67-78   ` 2017-01-11`
Match 12
Full match  79-80   ` `
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^;]                     any character except: ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ;                        ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ;                        ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```